# How to write codeigniter documentation

Tags: php, codeigniter, documentation

I've noticed that quite a few of the available codeigniter libraries use the same style of documentation that the main user guide uses (for example ion_auth http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/). Is there some sort of automated way to create this from source code comments, or are people just using cut and paste?

Answer (score 7):

They actually have information in the user guide about writing [CI documentation:](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/doc_style/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, evolve. I'd previously looked for this, but clearly I didn't look for longer than 10 seconds ;-)

Comment: I also did not see it. I was still hoping for something more automatic, like some sort of source comment parsing.

Comment: how do you go about creating the table of contents?